# Difference between a 7 speed chain and a 10 speed chain

Tags: gears

I have already upgraded to a 10 speed casette from a 7 speed freewheel. I was wondering if a 10 speed chain is narrower than a 7 speed?

Comment: that is an underrated question.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, while the internal width is the same, the external width of 10 speed chains is narrower.   Refer https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/chain-compatibility

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a 10 speed chain is significantly narrower than a 7 speed chain. Even considering that most people now use 8-speed chains even for 7 speeds. The difference can make shifting to stop working.

Comment: Beat you by 6 seconds :)